# Where to find Airflow SequentialExecutor worker error logs

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Airflow. I'm following the offical tutorial to set up the first DAG and task

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="hello_world_dag",
    description="Hello world DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 16),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_args
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="hello_task",
        bash_command="echo hello world!"
    )

    task1
```

When I tried to run this manually, it always failed. I've checked the web server logs and the scheduler logs, they don't have any obvious errors. I also checked the task run logs, it's empty.

The setup is pretty simple: SequentialExecutor with sqlite. My question is: where can I see the worker logs, or any other places that have any useful message logged?

Comment: Does the task fail immediately? Also which tutorial are you referring to? Can try to recreate it.

Comment: Just figured out the reason and posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally figured this out.

Firstly let me correct my question - there's actually an error raised in scheduler log that the "BashTaskRunner" cannot be loaded. So I searched Airflow's source code, and found it was renamed to StandardBashRunner like 3 years ago([link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/RELEASE_NOTES.rst)).

This is the only occurrence of the word `BashTaskRunner` in the whole repo. So I'm curious how the AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg is generated, which sets this as the default task_runner value.

Comment: That is interesting, normally airflow.cfg is generated when a specific Airflow instance is run for the first time with the standard config variables for that specific version ([config reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html)). So it is wild yours generated with a 3 years old config, did you install Airflow from the official Docs? You probably already know this but you can override values in airflow.cfg via ENV e.g. `AIRFLOW__CORE__TASK_RUNNER=StandardTaskRunner`.